# Azure AAD Portal registration app manifest unable to update

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have the app registered in Azure AAd app registration. The app was registered as mult tenant. Later i modified this to single tenant by changin the value in manifest Json data as

`"signInAudience": "AzureADMyOrg"`.

But I'm unable to update the "publisherDomain" value since it is null. if i try to update I'm getting the belwo error.

Can anyone tell me how to update this "Publisherdomain" value, otherwise how to change multi tenant app to single tenant (My org only) and what are the chages required to complete?

```
Error detail: Property 'publisherDomain' is read-only and cannot be set. [UMia4]
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to do change from multi-tenant to single tenant app will be to make use of the UI provided directly in Azure portal itself.

**Steps**

Azure Portal > Azure Active Directory > App registrations > registration for your application > Authentication > Supported account types

Change from `Accounts in any organizational directory` to `Accounts in this organizational directory only`

[image]

I tried creating a new app registration marking it as multi-tenant first (i.e. choosing `Accounts in any organizational directory` for supported account types) and then later changing it single tenant using the same steps from UI. The only change that I saw in app manifest, comparing the two JSON files before and after was the `signInAudience` changing from `AzureADMultipleOrgs` to `AzureADMyOrg`. There was no change in `publisherDomain` value. I'm not sure why you're trying to update it right now, but if there is a specific reason please mention that.

**About the error you're getting currently**

As the error message says already, it's a read only property so you will not be able to update the value.

Here is Microsoft Documentation on Azure AD App Manifest - [Understanding Azure AD app manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#manifest-reference). Look for `publisherDomain`.

Comment: Thanks Rohit. I tried the samething but it works same for me. But one of my old app the "publisherDomain " is null. I was suspecting it became null when i changed from multi tenant to single tenant. It was my misunderstanding. Now the problem is it always throws error "AADSTS50011".the reply url spcified in the url does not match the reply urls configured for the application:<appid>. So it hought it could be the issue because all my remaining settings looks fine.

Comment: I don't see the radio button. It shows like,
Who can use this application or access this API?
Accounts in any organizational directory and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox, Outlook.com)
All users with a work or school, or personal Microsoft account can use your application or API. This includes Office 365 subscribers.

To change the supported accounts for an existing registration, use the manifest editor. Take care, as certain properties may cause errors for personal accounts.

Comment: ok.. so your app registration is not just Multi-tenant, but it also allows personal accounts. **1)** In this case, you will need to change through app manifest. I tried doing this by creating an app with same setting as yours (multi-tenant + personal accounts) and then changing `singInAudience` to `AzureADMyOrg` which worked fine. **2)** About the error `AADSTS50011` have you tried adding the URL where you want Azure AD to redirect back with tokens after authenticating to your App Registration's Redirect URI's? Go to app registration overview > Redirect URIs > click on `Add a Redirect URI`

Comment: yes Rohit, Really thanks for your time. i added the redirect uri, it was working before i change this settings.I'm not sure it was because of this above tenant type change or some configuration messed up it is broken and showing the above error now. No  logs and troubleshoting guide for this.